# PHP upload photo to users facebook wall using php only

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to write a php script that can upload a daily photo to my personal facebook wall. I need this to be done at anytime and not just when I am logged in.  I am wondering if it is possible to upload a photo to my wall using php only or do I need to use an app with the right permissions. If so do I have to personally install that app and give correct permissions for my page to make this possible, if it is possible, and can this be done automatically?

**What I want to do:**
In short I want a users twitter feed to be converted and put on an image. I have the script that automatically does this already. However I would love it if after the twitter user tweets then this calls my script and converts it to an image (again I have done this code already) but...

Now I need a script that can automatically upload this to my personal wall after the image is created. Is this possible?

Comment: First you wrote: `my personal page facebook wall` ; then : `upload a photo to my wall` - so, you want to post photo to your wall or your page's wall?

Comment: My personal wall, when I said personal page I meant my person wall.

Comment: Are you aware of facebook basics - authentication, access tokens etc?

Comment: Yes, I am. Just wondering if the app can do it to a personal wall, with a photo, and without me needed to be logged in. For example, can my server run the php script and have my user id stored in a database and call that, with the facebook api and post to my wall...while I am sleeping. :)

Comment: Yes, it can – as long as you have a valid access token to pass with your request. User access tokens can be extended to 60 days, after that you’ll have to get a new one. Certain publishing actions are also possible using the app access token, if the user has given the app the right permissions before. If that works for photo uploads as well, I don’t know – you’ll have to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the extended user access token to get it working for a maximum of 60 days. After that, the token will expire and then you'll have to **refresh** the token and that is **not** possible without the user's interaction.

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) states the same:

> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app, so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background, if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to your app again.
>
> After doing the above you will obtain a new short-lived token and then you need to perform the same exchange for a long-lived token as above.

To get the extended token make the following call from your server:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
   grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
   client_id={app-id}&
   client_secret={app-secret}&
   fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

---

**Code**

```
$app_id = APP_ID;
   $app_secret = APP_SECRET;
   $post_login_url = APP_URL;
   $album_name = 'test';
   $album_description = 'desc';

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
   
     // access token
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];       // <---
    
     // extended token
     $extended_token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&fb_exchange_token=".$access_token; 
     $response = file_get_contents($extended_token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $extended_access_token = $params['access_token'];  //  <---

     // Upload to the photos to the album here
}
```

That's the complete auth process, incl the extended token. You can find many posts regarding the upload of the photo, simply use the `$extended_access_token` with your calls.

(In case you are not aware, [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a fantastic tool of facebook to test the APIs).

Good luck!

Comment: Hummm so do you have some sample code, the full thing I could use to achieve this? Like a call from my server with this special token stored and called?

Comment: Its not that complicated. I think you are able to get the normal user access token, just use that in the above call and you'll get the long-lived token (you can check this in the browser); and then use this tokoen with your call to `/photos`. If you find any difficulty let me know. Good luck!

Comment: you are the man btw. I have been doing research and I see your name all over on this subject. Thanks for the help! Good soul! :)

Comment: I am a fairly newbie at this to be honest. So Its going to take me some work to figure this out. I will get there. What I really want is the server to do it while I am away, like maybe use a 'offline access' call? Does that exist?

Comment: Hey Shadowfax, can you email me? I have a few questions for you. Thanks. ed.vizenor@gmail.com